# iAd not appear after app released to AppStore

Tags: ios, iad

My app "iCals" uploaded to AppStore and the iAd not appear.
In simulator and with TestFlight written in banner "You connected to iAd" but if I download the app from AppStore is not appear the banner.

```
@synthesize = adBanner = adBanner;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{



[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Make self the delegate of the ad banner.
adBanner.delegate = self;

// Initially hide the ad banner.
self.adBanner.alpha = 0.0;

}
```

Comment: As far as i remember iAd is connected to your location - if there are no ads for your location (country), the ad will not be served. It will always work in debug though.

Comment: If your app is iCal$, nice interface!

Answer (score 1):

iAd takes a couple of days to process *after* your app has already been processed and on the app store. If you go to the iAd dashboard you should have a message letting you know that your app is in review for iAd. If your app has only been in the app store for <3-5 days then give it a little more time. You'll still see the green light next to "Live Ads" but there won't be any ads until it's been reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the iAd control panel at https://iad.apple.com. If your app's Ad status is "Live ads", like so:

[image]

then everything is working fine, you just aren't getting an ad because there aren't always ads available to show. If you leave the app open for long enough, you should eventually see one.

You can also check other stats such as impression counts and fill rates in the control panel; these will indicate to you how many ads are actually being shown to users (my fill rates have been around 60% lately).

Also, if you don't live in one of the countries on [this list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203102), you'll never see any iAds in production.